# Twilio MVC , how do i make phone number/message dynamic

Tags: c#

I am using Visual studio. This is for Asp.net web application (.net framework)

this solution as a webcore application is acceptable as well.

I would like to be able to enter the information for message and to phone number dynamically , but i dont know how to "pause" the program so that this can happen. I understand the dynamic part, and can use Javascript to do that,

Basically what I want is an app that brings up a webpage where the end user enters the to number and the message, and then clicks send to send.

I thought it would be simple, but not so much :(

I have the quick start code for C# as -

```
// Install the C# / .NET helper library from twilio.com/docs/csharp/install

using System;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;


class Program 
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/console
    const string accountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    const string authToken = "your_auth_token";

    TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

    var message = MessageResource.Create(
        body: "Join Earth's mightiest heroes. Like Kevin Bacon.",
        from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+15017122661"),
        to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+15558675310")
    );

    Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
}
}
```

Comment: Well you'd have to get the user input, store it in a variable, then pass it to Twilio's API. If you're not sure how to get input from a user in a web application, then you need to go back to the web application tutorials and work through them. It's really too basic/broad of a topic for us to explain in a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: Are you trying to send the message via SMS or voice? Depending on what you need, the approach is a little different. It looks like you're using SMS, but I want to be sure before I type out an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I'm going to assume you want to send SMS. Further, I'm going to assume you're using Asp.Net MVC. Twilio voice is a little bit more complex, as Twilio calls back several times to get voice scripts and update statuses. More complex if you need phone tree behavior.

SMS Callbacks happen more than once too, but they're calling the same callback URL over and over, nothing fancy there.

The flow should look like this:
Web interface -> Asp.Net MVC Controller Action -> Database -> Twilio

I'll leave the web interface to you, and give some examples of the backend stuff.

You'll want a database, with one table 'Message'

Message should have these columns (at a minimum, you may need more):

**message_id_pk**

**twilio_sid** (nullable)

**message_content** (160 character limit if you want to keep messages in one SMS segment, this has considerations on operating cost)

**status** (nullable)

**recipient_phone**

Controller Action:

```
    [Authorize] //assuming you'll want to have users authenticate before they can send the sms
    [RequireHttps]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SendSMS(
                 [Bind(Include = "message_id_pk, message_content, recipient_phone"] Message message)
    {
        db.Messages.Add(message);
        TwilioSmsSender.SendSMS(message);
        return RedirectToAction("Success");
    }
```

And in TwilioSender.cs

```
public static void SendSMS(Message message)
{
const string accountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
const string authToken = "your_auth_token";

TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

var message = MessageResource.Create(
    body: message.message_content,
    from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+15017122661"), //note: you can let your Twilio Messaging service handle the phone number, I recommend you look into that
    to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(message.recipient_phone)
    statusCallback: new Uri(TwilioCallBackController.SMSCallBackURL)
);

message.twilio_sid = message.Sid;
db.SaveChanges();
}
```

And in TwilioCallBackController.cs (You need to handle callbacks from Twilio here)

```
    [ValidateTwilioRequest]
    public ActionResult TwilioSMSCallback()
    {
        string sid = Request.Form["SmsSid"];
        List<Message> msg = db.Message.Where(x=> x.twilio_sid == sid).ToListAsync();
        if(msg.Count > 0)
        {
            Message message = msg.First();
            message.status = Request.Form["SmsStatus"];
        }
    }
```